# Best analysis for finding impact of variables on margin over time

Tags: regression, time-series, linear-model

I have two data sets detailing item number, units sold, sales, COGS, and margin one year apart. I want to determine what had the greatest impact on margin from t1 to t2. This is broken down into 3 groups of item numbers:

*Like (same from t1 to t2)*

*New (did not appear in t1, but did in t2)*

*Lost (appeared in t1, but not in t2)*

So, overall what had the largest impact on margin? Like items increase in COGS/Unit? Lost items margin? Etc. My first thought was to run two linear regressions isolating all relevant variables and comparing the results. Will this result in what I am looking for? Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.